# Calculate measure across different time dimension tange

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a calculated measure `[Measures].[Person Count]` defined as `DISTINCTCOUNT(Visits[Person ID])`. Our fiscal year runs from July to June. I would like to pull a report showing, by fiscal month, both distinct person counts for that month as well as a running total. However, the running total also needs to take into account distinct values. Here is what I have that *almost* works:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Cumulative Person Count] AS 
     Sum(PeriodsToDate([Date].[Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Year], 
                       [Date].[Fiscal Calendar].CurrentMember),
         [Measures].[Person Count])
SELECT [Date].[Fiscal Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS ON COLUMNS,
       { [Measures].[Person Count], 
         [Measures].[Cumulative Person Count] } ON ROWS
  FROM [Model]
 WHERE [Date].[FiscalYear].&[2018]
```

This gives something like the following:

```
+-------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+...
|                         |  July | August | September |...
+-------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+...
| Person Count            | 34268 |  37270 |     35971 |...
| Cumulative Person Count | 34268 |  71538 |    107509 |...
+-------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+...
```

The "Person Count" numbers are correct. The "Cumulative Person Count", however, is merely summing up the totals from each month, ignorant of the duplicates. Suppose that only 10% of person records are new each month. The result I would like to see would be something like the following:

```
+-------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+...
|                         |  July | August | September |...
+-------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+...
| Person Count            | 34268 |  37270 |     35971 |...
| Cumulative Person Count | 34268 |  37995 |     41592 |...
+-------------------------+-------+--------+-----------+...
```

What is the best way to reuse the `[Measures].[Person Count]` measure but apply it to a different range that is aware of the context?

Comment: Can you not do something like this:
WITH SET MySet AS {[Visits].[Person ID].Members}*{[Date].[FiscalYear].&[2018]}
MEMBER Measures.DistinctFiscalYearCount AS DISTINCTCOUNT(MySet)

Answer (score 0):

You might just be using the incorrect aggregation type - try `AGGREGATE` instead:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Cumulative Person Count] AS 
     AGGREGATE(
        PeriodsToDate(
            [Date].[Fiscal Calendar].[Fiscal Year], 
            [Date].[Fiscal Calendar].CurrentMember),
         [Measures].[Person Count]
     )
```

An alternative to `PeriodsToDate` may be the use of `NULL:..`:

```
AGGREGATE(
    { NULL : [Date].[Fiscal Calendar].CurrentMember } 
    ,[Measures].[Person Count]
)
```